# Can you identify this bug

Tags: species-identification

[image]
This was found in my home in Mojave county Arizona. It was about 1/8 inch long. I have a cat. Hoping not a flea.

Comment: Definitely not a flea. It has the mouthparts of a true bug, order Hemiptera. I can't tell beyond that.

Comment: If the specimen is still at hand, adding a top view photo would help get an answer as to what true bug we're seeing here (but if the primary concern was flea or not, that's been dealt with).

Comment: I don't have it anymore. I Would like to know what it is, but yes my concern was flea. Me and my cat keep getting bit up. I have seen lacewing and thrips in house and on me. I know the larvae stage of both feed on blood. Also thrips are known to lay eggs under people skins. Pretty sure all these stupid little bugs are tearing us up. Just trying to identify  everything I see. So I can prevent as much as possible